# Backbone.Collection.Create not triggering "add" in view

Tags: backbone.js

Hopefully this is an easy question.  I'm trying to learn backbone and i'm stuck on a really simple thing.  the render on the view never gets called when I update the collection by using the create method.  I thought this should happen without explicitly calling render.  I'm not loading anything dynamic, it's all in the dom before this script fires.  The click event works just fine and I can add new models to the collection, but the render in the view never fires.

```
$(function(){

window.QuizMe = {};

// create a model for our quizzes
QuizMe.Quiz = Backbone.Model.extend({
// override post for now
"sync": function (){return true},

});

QuizMe._QuizCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: QuizMe.Quiz,
});

QuizMe.QuizCollection = new QuizMe._QuizCollection

QuizMe.QuizView = Backbone.View.extend({

el:$('#QuizMeApp'),

template: _.template($('#quizList').html()),

events: {
  "click #addQuiz" : "addQuizDialog",
},

initialize: function() {
// is this right?
  _.bindAll(this,"render","addQuizDialog")
  this.model.bind('add', this.render, this);

},

addQuizDialog: function(event){
  console.log('addQuizDialog called')
  QuizMe.QuizCollection.create({display:"this is a display2",description:"this is a succinct description"});  
},

render: function() {
  console.log("render called")
},
});

QuizMe.App = new QuizMe.QuizView({model:QuizMe.Quiz})

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you're binding to the *model*:

```
this.model.bind('add', this.render, this);
```

but you're adding to a *collection*:

```
QuizMe.QuizCollection.create({
    display:     "this is a display2",
    description: "this is a succinct description"
});
```

A view will usually have an associated collection or model but not both. If you want your `QuizView` to list the known quizzes then:

1. You should probably call it `QuizListView` or something similar.
2. Create a new `QuizView` that displays a single quiz; this view would have a model.
3. Rework your `QuizListView` to work with a collection.

You should end up with something like this:

```
QuizMe.QuizListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    initialize: function() {
        // You don't need to bind event handlers anymore, newer
        // Backbones use the right context by themselves.
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection.bind('add', this.render);
    },
    addQuizDialog: function(event) {
        this.collection.create({
            display:     "this is a display2",
            description: "this is a succinct description"
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log("render called")
        // And some stuff in here to add QuizView instances to this.$el
        return this; // Your render() should always do this.
    }
});

QuizMe.App = new QuizMe.QuizView({ collection: QuizMe.QuizCollection });
```

And watch that trailing comma after `render`, older IEs get upset about that and cause difficult to trace bugs.

I'd give you a quick demo but http://jsfiddle.net/ is down at the moment. When it comes back, you can start with http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RRXnK/ to play around, that fiddle has all the appropriate Backbone stuff (jQuery, Backbone, and Underscore) already set up.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  I never thought about how i was binding to the model but adding through the collection.  thanks for the extremely helpful insight!!

Comment: @SneakyWombat: Cheers. You can find various other mini Backbone apps in my other Backbone answers (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:479863+[backbone.js]), a lot of them have little jsfiddles attached.

Comment: have to say thanks again, i actually have a working app now.  thanks again!!  a lot of confusion has been cleared up.

Comment: @SneakyWombat: Glad to be service. Backbone does take a bit of getting used to but it is pretty nice once you get your head around the basic approach. You should read up on [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) as well, you'll have it loaded when you're using Backbone so you might as well use it.