# Backbone.js and underscore.js binding this to this.collection.add

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having problems with a tutorial that uses

```
this.collection.bind('add',appendItem)
```

and

```
this.collection.bind('add',appendSet)
```

appendItem is a function defined within a backbone.js view for a collection of views. Same for appendSet The problem is that I want to expand on the tutorial by having nested models, but when I add an item, if I use the above lines the I've bound appendItem and appendSet to the add function, so the add function won't know what this is supposed to be.

(quick reminder on what bind does: http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

So how do I still use

```
this.collection.add(thisItem)
```

and still avoid the binding problem. **In short**: is there a way to call this.collection.add(thisItem) and tell the add function that the keyword 'this' is supposed to refer to appendItem without using the bind function?

If requested I can include my code but I thought it was a little long and unwieldy, and likely not useful anyway.

EDIT:

The logic of my code is this. An item is a model with several attributes and a collection of sets associated with it. I am just following a tutorial and the way he got these objects to render was he used this.collection.bind('add',appendItem) so that when you called this.collection.add, appendItem would be called. Here is the code for appendItem:

```
appendItem: function(item){
       alert("append exercise called in allExerciseview");
       var itemView=new ItemView({
         model: Item
       });
       $('ul',this.el).append(itemView.renderItem().el);
      }
```

I can't find the source code for this.collection.add, but I'm assuming having this in that function refer to appendItem calls the appendItem function. **In short:** the reason is that  this code:

```
this.collection.bind('add',appendItem)
```

makes it so that when you call

```
this.collection.add(thisItem)
```

it also runs

```
thisItem.appendItem()
```

Unbinding them and just running this.collection.add(thisItem) and then seperately running thisItem.appendItem() isn't working for me.

MY SAMPLE CODE:

```
(function($){
    Backbone.sync = function(method, model, success, error) {
        success();
    };

    var Set = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            SetName:"Set "
            //more properties...
        },
        initialize: function(){
            alert("you've created a new set");
            this.bind("error",function(model,error){
                alert(error);
            });
        }
    });

    var SetCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Set
    });

    var SetView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'click button.deleteSet': 'removeSet'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            alert('initialize called in setview');
            _.bindAll(this,'renderSet', 'unrenderSet', 'removeSet');
        /*this.model.bind('change',this.renderSet);
         this.model.bind('remove',this.unrender); Not sure if I should do this*/
            return this; //apparently for chainable calls    
        },
        renderSet: function(){
            alert('renderset called in setview');
            $(this.el).html('a set template'); //add button after so you can test delete
            return this;
        },
        unrenderSet: function(){
            alert('unrenderset called in setview');
            $(this.el).remove();
        },
        removeSet: function(){
            alert('removeset called in setview');
            this.model.destroy();
        }
    });

    var AllSetView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('body'), //el attaches to existing element <-- what does this mean?
        events: {
            'click button#addSetButton': 'addSet'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            alert('initialize called in allsetview');
            _.bindAll(this,'renderAllSet', 'addSet', 'appendSet');
            this.collection = new SetCollection();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.appendSet); // Problem here...
            this.counter = 0;
            this.renderAllSet(); 
        },
        renderAllSet: function(){
            alert('renderallset called in allsetview');
            var self = this; 
            $(this.el).append('<button id="addSetButton"> Add Set </button>');
            $(this.el).append('<ul></ul>');
            _(this.collection.models).each(function(set){ //in case collection is not empty
                self.appendSet(set);
            },this); 
        },
        addSet: function(){
            alert('addSet called in allsetview');
            this.counter++;
            var thisSet = new Set();
            thisSet.set({SetName:thisSet.get('SetName')+this.counter});
            this.collection.add(thisSet); //add is a function defined for the collection
        },
        appendSet: function(item){
            alert("append set called in allsetview");
            var setView = new SetView({
                model: Set //DO NOT CAPITALIZE!!!... or do capitalize?... ack
            });
            $('ul',this.el).append(setView.renderSet().el);
        }
    });

    var allsetview = new AllSetView(); //for testing

    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            ItemName: 'Enter an Item'
            //more properties
        },
        initialize: function(){
            alert('youve created a new item');
            var set1 = new Set();
            var setCollection = new SetCollection([set1]);
            this.set({sets:setCollection});
            this.bind("error",function(model,error){
                alert(error);
            });
        }
    });

    var ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Item
    });

    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'click button.deleteItem': 'removeItem'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            alert('initialize called in itemview');
            _.bindAll(this,'renderItem', 'unrenderItem', 'removeItem');
            //this.model.bind('change',this.renderItem);
            //this.model.bind('remove',this.unrender); Not sure if I should do this
            return this; //apparently for chainable calls    
        },
        renderItem: function(){
            alert('renderitem called in Itemview');
            $(this.el).html('an item template'); //add button after so you can test delete
            return this;
        },
        unrenderItem: function(){
            alert('unrenderitem called in itemview');
            $(this.el).remove();
        },
        removeItem: function(){
            alert('removeItem called in itemview');
            this.model.destroy();
        }
    });

    alert ("before itemview creation");
    var itemview = new ItemView();
    alert ("now after");

    var AllItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('body'), //el attaches to existing element <-- what does this mean?
        events: {
            'click button#addItemButton': 'addItem'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            alert('initialize called in allitemview');
            _.bindAll(this,'renderAllItem', 'addItem', 'appendItem');
            this.collection = new ItemCollection();
            this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem); //Problem here
            this.counter = 0;
            this.renderAllItem(); 
        },
        renderAllItem: function(){
            alert('renderallitem called in allitemview');
            var self = this; //why
            $(this.el).append('<button id="addItemButton"> Add Item </button>');
            $(this.el).append('<ul></ul>');
            _(this.collection.models).each(function(item){ //in case collection is not empty
                self.appendItem(item);
            },this); //what is this function
        },
        addItem: function(){
            alert('addItem called in allitemview');
            this.counter++;
            var thisItem = new Item();
            thisItem.item({ItemName:thisItem.get('ItemName')+this.counter
            });
            this.collection.add(thisItem); //add is a function defined for the collection
            this.appendItem(thisItem);
        },
        appendItem: function(item){
            alert("append item called in allItemview");
            var itemView = new ItemView({
                model: Item //DO NOT CAPITALIZE!!!... or do capitalize?... 
            });
            $('ul',this.el).append(itemView.renderItem().el);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why are you binding two different methods to the same collection callback? Are you trying to do something when a single item is added versus when the ENTIRE set of items is added?  (This has nothing to do with a nested model though, which is an entirely separate question)

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal is to render some sort of hierarchy.

First off:
In the appendItem function shouldn't the model for itemView be `model:item` instead of `model:Item`. I don't see Item defined anywhere.

Next, why aren't you using?: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

appendItem seems redundant. It also seems like you would like to add a new view once your collection is changed. Well in that case you may want to have a View for your Collection or Router for the App that binds events to changes. This question might help?: [Backbone.Collection.Create not triggering "add" in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627598/backbone-collection-create-not-triggering-add-in-view)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll add my code so you can see what I'm really doing/getting wrong. one sec. Again I'm just following a tutorial so I don't have good reasons for everything I'm doing ><

Comment: You're completely right in that I'm trying to render a hierarchy. The problem is that the tutorial that I'm following relies on binding add and AppendItem or AppendSet respectively. This causes problems when you have a hierarchy. I want to know how to do it in a way that allows me to have a hierarchy.

Comment: Does it add the item to the collection or does it just not render it?

Comment: Currently it adds the item to the collection and but add fails to call appendItem, and appendItem is what renders the item.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that appendItem was in the view. It makes sense, but I think it voids the convention a bit. You should be binding events to your models or collections so that when something changes in them they get rendered. However, your addItem function makes sense. I believe in appendItem you should be appending `item` not `Item`. Item is a class not an object. You are creating views that represent objects not classes.

Comment: I don't understand though. It says model:, so I should be specifying a model, no? Item is a model. item is an instantiation of that model.

Comment: When I was learning, this tutorial seemed really helpful: http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html

Check out the source. I also tried to do other things for displaying hierarchies like just using models and no collections. However, an Item containing a Collection that contains items is a standard Tree or directed Graph configuration.

Comment: Item is a model, but think about what a model is used for. A model is a way to tie data and code together. Your data is stored in an instance of a model class. If you pass a model class no data is there to create a view from. If an instance of a view is a template then you should fill it with data, which is represented by an instance of a model.

see:
`addOne: function(todo) {
      var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
      this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
    }`

Comment: Correction!!! this.collection.add is never called! I have no idea why, more on this later.

Comment: Is addItem ever called? I believe it has to do with your selectors. I had issues with selectors and how events were delegated to parent elements when I started as well.

Comment: You are completely correct, I just figured out the problem and it has to do with the selectors. I will post a full answer as soon as I have it