# Backbone events not firing as expected

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

I initialise the View:

```
notifications = new tvr.notifications.Collection
notifications.fetch()
new tvr.notifications.View collection:notifications
```

Im adding "notifications" to a backbone collection:

```
notifications =  new tvr.notifications.Collection
notifications.fetch()
notifications.create html:this_notification
```

notifications.coffee

```
    class Notifiction extends Backbone.Model
    class Notifictions extends Backbone.Collection
        model = Notifiction
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'tvr.notifications'


    class NotificationView extends Backbone.View
        initialize: ->
            @listenTo @collection, "add", @update

        update: ->
            alert "update"

    namespace 'tvr.notifications', (exports) ->
        exports.Model = Notifiction
        exports.Collection = Notifictions
        exports.View = NotificationView
```

this events are never called, I can see the objects created in the collection.

I just want to know when A new one is added, or deleted from the collection, so I can update a badge number in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind the `"Add"` event to a function call, which is not possible. You need to bind the event to a function reference and Backbone's event mechanism will call the function that is referenced on your behalf. Without using `alert`, here is an example of the difference (in JavaScript).

**Function to invoke**

```
var myFunc = function() {
    alert("happy days");
}
```

**Illegal**

```
notifications.on("add", myFunc());
```

**Legal**

```
notifications.on("add", myFunc);
```

So you can see in your example you are trying to call the `alert` function and pass an argument of `"happy days"` when you bind it using `on`. This is not allowed.

However if you write a parameter-less function that wraps the code you would like to call such as in the `myFunc` example above and assign it to a variable or other object, you can bind the event to the function's reference. This should then behave the way you are expecting.

Lastly, you should bind the event using `listenTo`, not `on`. This is for reasons already discussed on SO. For further reference read the following:

[Difference between ListenTo and on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041042/backbone-0-9-9-difference-between-listento-and-on)

[Backbone js .listenTo vs .on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823746/backbone-js-listento-vs-on)

Comment: I did as you explained, but this does not work. I updated my question

Comment: You may need a `_.bindAll(this)` as the first line of your `initialize` function. Also, I can't see any evidence you are adding models to the `Notifictions` collection. you don't even have a reference to it in your example as you `new` it in the `listenTo` function. So how can you be adding models to it?

Comment: Its in the question, line 1 and 2. ill try bindAll

Comment: I think I know whats wrong, the **View** is listening to the collection events and you never pass the view the collection you call `create` on. You need to pass the `notifications` collection to the view as a parameter opon initialization.  **Before** you call `create` on the collection`. Also, change `@listenTo new Notifictions, "add", @upate` to `@listenTo @collection, "add", @upate` (or similar, my coffeescript aint the best :)

Comment: bindAll does not work , this guy had the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627598/backbone-collection-create-not-triggering-add-in-view

Comment: Yup I tried that to, I added the collection to View before anything was done to the collection as you suggested and in the other question I posted above.

Comment: Are you calling the first 5 lines of code in that order? If so, delete line 4 and swap lines 2 & 3.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33203/discussion-between-harry-and-dcarson)